# Coq transparency issues with type class fields

Tags: math-software, automated-theorem-proving, theorem-provers

I am having some issues with, I suspect, transparency of fields in type classes. Consider a type class such as

```
Class CommutativeOperator
  ( Carrier : Type )
  ( Equality : relation Carrier )
  ( Op : operator Carrier ) : Prop := {
    equality := Equality where "a ≡ b" := (equality a b).
  ; op       := Op       where "a ⋆ b" := (op a b).

  ; commutative_proper : Proper (equality ==> equality ==> equality) op

  ; commutativity : ∀ a b, a ⋆ b ≡ b ⋆ a
}.
```

And some object derived from the fields `equality` and `op`. Take for example

```
Definition square { L } `{ CommutativeOperator L } ( a : L ) := (op a a).
```

The problem is, now, that when one unfolds `square` it uses the name `op` rather than the name of the operator in the inferred instance, which is an issue, for example, when one is working with multiple instances of `CommutativeOperator` at once (meaning the names from the instances are needed to disambiguate). Continuing by unfolding `op` makes it use the names from the instance but, I am guessing due to some transparency reasons, results in the operator no longer being considered commutative, i.e. one can no longer rewrite with `commutativity` (doing so results in a "goal contains no subterm of the form a ⋆ b").

Is there some way for me to keep the convenience of fields like `equality` and `op` without confusing instance resolution when rewriting?

EDIT: Turns out what I needed to do was use the setoid_rewrite tactic (after unfolding op).

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, no question is asked here. (This reminds me of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36676.)

Comment: You're quite right, I'll fix it.